# Is there a way to remove all sticky options in CVS?

Tags: sticky, cvs, removeall

I have accidentally commited a file to CVS as binary (sticky option -kb), and now I would like to remove it. Is it possible?

I've found a way to change the option to something else with cvs admin -kv , but is there a way to remove it completely?

I've also tried to remove the file and then re-add again (without specifying any sticky options), but also the new revision of the file has the same old -kb option.

Thanks!

Comment: What types and versions of CVS are you using (both client and server are relevant)? CVSNT offers a couple of additional options over CVS when it comes to versioning substitution modes.

Comment: The server has: "Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.11.21 (client/server)"
The client is either the same (if I use the server machine), or I may use the CVS team synchronization features from Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the binary flag with repo surgery as follows:

1. Edit the `file,v` stored in the repo and delete the line(s) with `expand  @b@;`.
2. If you have checked out versions of `file`, edit `CVS/Entries` and remove the `-kb` for `file` at the end of `/file/1.1/Mon Sep  9 09:30:10 2013/-kb/` so the line ends with `//`.

That did the trick here.

Comment: Thanks for a solution! So, if I edit only in repository but not in the checked out (e.g. by person A) files, then once the person A commits, the flag will get re-added again?

Comment: I haven't tried, but to be sure it's best if all user check in their files, delete or release their working copy, then you do surgery, then check out again.

Answer (score 0):

From https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/info-cvs/2000-10/msg00620.html
I tried this already and it works.

For example you have a file named "abc".

```
cvs update -A abc
cvs admin -kkv abc
cvs update -A abc
cvs status abc
```

Note: Make sure to do the cvs update after the cvs admin because your local file will not be automatically updated after the cvs admin.

Answer (score -1):

No:

- There is no command for this
- It was not designed for this

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply! The lack of the command, however, doesn't seem like a design decision to me, as there IS a command to change the sticky option. Setting it to "none" is something just not implemented.